# How to make a JS script run in all tabs from a given window in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, global

I am a newbie and a Firefox user.

I want to change the tab's titles to something that's easier for me to read. On a given tab, I can easily modify in the console `document.title` to a name output by my script.

**Is there a way to make this script run in all tabs opened in a given window, or must I open the console in each tab and run the script there?**

If possible, I'd prefer answers that don't need SDK, that can only use the regular console/options from Firefox.

Comment: you might consider an extension.

Comment: JavaScript can not do cross-tab scripting in the browser (it is a security risk).

Comment: @Daniel A. White any suggestions of extensions? I'm not savvy enough to make one by my own, and it makes no sense to learn all of it just for this

Comment: @flen, *"it makes no sense to learn all of it just for this"* It's not *just for this*, once you'll have learned how to do it, you'll be able to make more interesting extensions as well. Knowledge is not only valuable at *t* time. If you already know a bit of js, writing an extension is not that hard. It's also in js, it's just that you've got more powerful APIs than default Web APIs.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara Brilliant! I'm gonna try one with Greasemonkey addon

Comment: [A starting guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), and something [more focused on your actual problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Content_windows).

Comment: @Kaiido you're right, it's just that I'm rather without time. Heck, I've even learned JavaScript out of curiosity, I'm not a programmer, and it's super useful to me. But I'd also need a fairly simple tutorial, do you happen to know one? When I tried MDN I couldn't really understand it well. EDIT: Oh, great! thanks for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arber Sylejmani is right, I think it's not possible even via console (in contrast to an embedded JS). But @Alexander O'Mara nailed it, I just had to install a Greasemonkey addon. Then you can do the scripts you like and apply it to all tabs.

Example:

Greasemonkey's icon -> "New user script" -> name: "Change title" -> namespace: "Change title" -> include: (here comes a list of URLs that will trigger the script if the tab uses one of those URLs. For example, if I want to make the script run only on tabs from stackoverflow, then:) " https://stackoverflow.com/* " (without quotes)

Then comes a regular JS script. Say: `document.title = document.location.href;` . Or whatever. This is a good tutorial: http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/the-beginner-s-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247